# Regex format to find a specific string from the list

Tags: python, regex

*This is not for homework!*

Hello,

Just a quick question about `Regex` formatting.

I have a list of different courses.

`L = ['CI101', 'CS164', 'ENGL101', 'I-', 'III-', 'MATH116', 'PSY101']`

I was looking for a format to find all the words that start with `I`, or `II`, or `III`. Here is what I did. (I used python fyi)

```
for course in L:
    if re.search("(I?II?III?)*", course):
        L.pop()
```

I learned that `?` in regex means optional. So I was thinking of making `I`, `II`, and `III` optional and `*` to include whatever follows.  However, it seems like it is not working as I intended. What would be a better working format?

Thanks

Comment: `re.match('^I{1,3}.*$')`, please see https://regex101.com/r/HDS4TX/1.

Comment: Aha, Thank you!

Comment: @Yang Do you mind making that an answer so the question can be resolved?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I've forgot this question :) @NiayeshIsky

Comment: Yang's regex is correct, but note that your Python code won't work as intended: the `pop()` operation will always remove the first element in the list. Consider using a list comprehension like so: `[ c for c in courses if re.match("^I{1,3}.*", c) ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the regex you should use:

```
^I{1,3}.*$
```

[click here to see example](https://regex101.com/r/HDS4TX/1)

`^` means the head of a line. `I{1,3}` means repeat `I` 1 to 3 times. `.*` means any other strings. `$` means the tail of a line. So this regex will match all the words that start with `I`, `II`, or `III`.

Look at your regex, first, you don't have the `^` mark, so it will match `I` anywhere. Second, `?` will only affect the previous one character, so the first `I` is optional,  but the second `I` is not, then the third `I` is optional, the fourth and fifth `I` are not, the sixth `I` is optional. Finally, you use parentheses with `*`, that means the expression in parentheses will repeat many times include 0 time. So it will match 0 `I`, or at least 3 `I`.

[your regex](https://regex101.com/r/C49TPK/1)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `search()` you can use the function `match()` that matches the pattern at the beginning of string:

```
import re

l = ['CI101', 'CS164', 'ENGL101', 'I-', 'III-', 'MATH116', 'PSY101']

pattern = re.compile(r'I{1,3}')

[i for i in l if not pattern.match(i)]
# ['CI101', 'CS164', 'ENGL101', 'MATH116', 'PSY101']
```